# New Entry Template button is disabled

Tags: filenet-p8, filenet, ibm-content-navigator

I have configured the ICN to use the entry templates using the following procedure

1. Open the administration tool in the web client. Click Repositories
   and open the repository on which you want to enable entry template
   management.
2. Connect to the repository as a library server administrator (IBM® Content Manager) or a Content Platform Engine administrator (IBM FileNet® P8).
3. In the Optional Features section of
   the Configuration Parameters tab, select Enable for the entry
   template management feature.

I have been able to see the entry template feature on the ICN, however I am unable to create any new entry template as the "New Entry Template" button is disabled.

Comment: What version of ICN and what repository do you use?

Comment: Build Level icn203.555 (201409021146)
Version 2.0.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your Access. Are you member of the group for Entry Template Management?
I suggest to clear browser cache and cookies, restart browser. 
If that doesn't help try to restart back-end and ICN.

Comment: For some weird reason it turned out that the back-end needs to be restarted